# App gives off __dyld_dyld_fatal_error on simulator, WORKING and FINE on device

Tags: ios-simulator, ios5, xcode4.2, dyld

I was scouring over stackoverflow and somehow unable to find the answer to my problem. My app builds and compiles just fine, but when i try to run it on the simulator, it throws a __dyld_dyld_fatal_error(). However, when i try to run it on an iOS device, everything is smooth. On a side note, I've have just updated my XCode version to XCode 4.2 to support iOS5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I had to reset the settings on my simulator before having to run it without any glitches, and made sure of the correct version of iOS that the application has to run on.